# How to filter a List<Customer> filled with Objects

Tags: c#, .net, generics, generic-list, generic-collections

I have a class Person and a list of type `List<Person>`

```
class person
{  
    int id;
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
}
```

I have ten Person objects filled it the List.

My List is bound to Jqgrid. On Paging i want to filter the List and bind the grid with the data for that Page.

So if anyone can tell me how to do paging on a `List<Person>`

Comment: Which language? Assuming C# from the .net-generics tag...but want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you are trying to filter the List or page the results. The typical way to page results is using a combination of `Skip()` and `Take()`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Page(this List<T> list, int pageSize, int pageNum)
{
    return list.Skip(pageSize * pageNum).Take(pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Justing. You got it right. I needed to page. This helps. Thanks :-)